# flask bot api - concurrent requests

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a backend for a Facebook messenger bot but code seems to have problems when multiple users are talking to the system at the same time (through messenger platform).

My stack is:
Flask
Flask-sqlalchemy (connected to an MS SQL DB on Azure)
stack is running on azure web app

simplified app structure is as follows:

`app/
   ___init___.py
   mod_bot/
      bot.py
   mod_db/
      model.py
      tools.py`

app is created as follows:

app/__ init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request, Response
import traceback
import app.mod_bot.bot as bot
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('AbiBotApp.config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            bot.process_incoming(json.loads(request.get_data(as_text=True)))
            return Response(status=200)
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

elif request.method == 'GET':
    if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == app.config['VERIFY_TOKEN']:
        return Response(request.args.get('hub.challenge'), status=200)
    return Response("Error, invalid token", status=200)`
```

The bot module processes requests and sends messages back to user. Processing of the "get_next_message" function takes time and also calls the DB for additional data (excluded here for simplicity). Clearly during this time, other requests can be made to the app.

app/mod_bot/bot.py:

```
from app import app
import json
import app.mod_db.tools as db_tools

def process_incoming(data):
    user = db_tools.get_user(data['id'])
    last_message = user.last_message
    new_message = data['message']

    next_message = get_next_message(last_message, new_message)
    user = db_tools.update_user(user, next_message)
    send_message(user, next_message)

...
def get_next_message(last_message, new_message):
    # CONVERSATION LOGIC

def send_message(user, next_message):
    # SEND MESSAGE TO FB API
```

I separated DB operations and model into the following:

app/mod_db/model.py:

```
from app import db

# ---- USER DATA MODEL ---- #
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    last_message = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

app/mod_db/tools.py:

```
from app import app, db
from app.mod_db.model import User

def get_user(id):
    """ Find existing user """
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == int(id)).first()
    return user

def update_user(user, last_message):
    user.last_message = last_message
    db.session.commit()
return user
```

This all works fine when just one user is talking to the app (through the messenger platform), however when multiple people are interacting there seems to be a problem. The main problem being that users receive each others next messages...

I'm assuming that I have misunderstood how flask and sqlalchemy handle multiple concurrent requests / how the flask app context works or something like that.

I also suspect that my app structure isn't particularly sensible (although that may not be causing the problem).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: next_message = get_next_message(last_message, next_message) - what's this? I don't see next_message defined before this, so how can you be passing it?

Comment: Sorry, small typo... I've just updated it.... I'm passing "new_message" not "next_message"

Comment: probably not an answer either, but why are you returning and reassigning user through `update_user`?

Comment: I wasn't sure about this but I sometimes have more complex updates to objects and usually did the updating and commit in a separate function (as above), just returning the updated object... I was under the impression that this should still return the correct object though? Unless different processes are being called when this happens and somehow they are overlapping?

Comment: it is returning the current object, but it's not updating it, the way you have it written now, you get user, do something using user and return it unchanged, which is pointless

Comment: surely user.last_message = last_message is updating the object before it is returned?

Comment: oh yes now I see it, I'm dumb, sorry! What I would do in your place is add a few print/log statements and track the messages and what's happening to them, I couldn't spot any error in this code and it should work as expected.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see if I can do that... in the meantime, I don't suppose you know of a good guide / example for creating (server side) stateful web apps using flask?

Comment: Can't say that I do, sorry